# Double with exactly two decimal digits in java (without java.text.DecimalFomat)

Tags: java, decimal

I have double var and I need to make it in 0.00 format. Works fine with this:

```
sum = Math.round(sum*100.00)/100.00;
```

I return it by

```
return Double.toString(sum);
```

But instead of for example 2.40 it gives me 2.4 (missing 0 at the end).

I have these imports available:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*; import java.util.*;import org.junit.Test;
```

I solved the problem with DecimalFormat and BigDecimal, but i can't use those libraries.

Comment: Why without `DecimalFormat`? NB These are not 'decimal numbers', they are floating-point variables with real values.

Comment: Without DecimalFormat becouse it's for the app, where I can only write part of a code. Thanks for hint with the decimal numbers, I've learned math in other language than english, so it's hard to process terminology sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple `format` the String

```
double num = 2.402;
String output = String.format("%.2f", num);
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.String#format()` or `java.util.Formatter` to print the number in a convenient manner.

```
return String.format("%.2f", sum);
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use format
example:

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StringDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   double piVal = Math.PI;

   /* returns a formatted string using the specified format
   string, and arguments */
   System.out.format("%f\n", piVal);
   }
    }
output: 3.141593
```

The %f allows for the amount of digits you wanna incudes ot %.2f includes 2 digits after.
[image]